# Want to stop milliseconds from increasing

Tags: java, android, time, milliseconds

I'm trying to create a timer app, but I have this problem with milliseconds.

When someone activates the timer I save the current milliseconds and then I just this to get the difference between them

`long startMillisecond;
 long i = System.currentMillisecond() - startMillisecond`

and then I display this variable `i` with some other code. However when I pause my program my variable `i` stays on the right value, but when I start the program again I get the "wrong" value since `System.currentMillisecond()` keeps increasing (internally), so it looks like it "jumps" over a couple of seconds

Example: Start app > variable `i = System.currentMillisecond() - startMillisecond` is equal to 0. And now if I pause for 5 seconds and then resume my variable `i` have the value of 5.

Anyone knows how I can let it be on the same value when I paus?

**EDIT. Here is my code for my run function**

```
String tempstring;

int millisec,sec,min,hour;

Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;

SensorManager mSensor;
Sensor accSensor;

Button startButton,stopButton,resetButton;
TextView whiteplayertime,blackplayertime,xt,yt,zt;

public void StartTimer(View view){
    mSensor.registerListener(this, accSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

           if(startmillisec <= 0){
                startmillisec = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }        
            tempmillisec = System.currentTimeMillis() - startmillisec;

            millisec = tempmillisec;
            millisec /= 100;
            millisec = millisec % 10;
            sec = TU.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tempmillisec);
            sec = sec % 60;
            min = TU.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tempmillisec);
            min = min % 60;
            hour = TU.MILLISECONDS.toHours(tempmillisec);
            hour = hour % 24;
            tempstring = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%d",hour,min,sec,millisec);
            whiteplayertime.setText(tempstring);
            handler.post(this); //This is the last in the code
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: Can you add your whole code?

Comment: You want the timer to run only when your app is active/in the foreground?

Comment: @HannoBinder only when active yes.

Comment: Then you can use the approach from @Davide's answer. Just make sure you save the elapsed time when your activity pauses and restore it when it resumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple save elapsed from the last stop value and save in a variable if the timer is ongoing or not.

```
public MyTimer {
    private long startTime;
    private long elapsed;
    private boolean running;

    public void start() {
        startTime = System.currentTimemillis();
        running = true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        elapsed = elapsed + System.currentTimemillis() - startTime; 
        running = false;   
    }

    public long getElapsed() {
        if (running) {
            return elapsed + System.currentTimemillis() - startTime;
        } else {
            return elapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you find this answer useful you can flag it as the right answer with the green flag. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the time in pause. Keep, on pause

`long pauseTime=System.currentMillisecond()`

and on un-pause

`long timeInPause = System.currentMillisecond()-pauseTime`

then

`i= System.currentMillisecond() - startMillisecond - timeInPause`

Comment: This seems nice and easy to understand also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 field. 
StartPause the time in MS when the pause started. 
EndPause the time in MS when the pause stopped. 
TotalPause total pause time.

Every time the user pauses and continues add the difference to the total pause time.  Subtract this from your total time